# Excel VBA Macro Array Limit

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm relatively new to Macro's in Excel (more of a java programmer) so I've written something to simply delete all the rows in a sheet for a colleague of mine.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub DeleteFirstPart()
Dim MyArray
MyArray = Array(455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 578, 593, 628, 638, 643, 679, 683, 754, 755, 759, 817, 826, 830, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 881, 885, 891, 892, 899, 900, 905, 911, 914, 915, 916, 923, 928)
For i = UBound(MyArray) To LBound(MyArray) Step -1
Rows(MyArray(i)).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
End Sub


Sub DeleteSecondPart()
Dim MyArray
MyArray = Array(100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 109, 112, 113, 114, 116, 120, 127, 139, 141, 148, 151, 165, 172, 185, 187, 189, 191, 196, 198, 201, 237, 240, 242, 243, 244, 246, 249, 253, 256, 271, 276, 282, 322, 323, 325, 330, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454)
For i = UBound(MyArray) To LBound(MyArray) Step -1
Rows(MyArray(i)).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
End Sub

Sub DeleteThirdPart()
Dim MyArray
MyArray = Array(2, 6, 24, 30, 31, 34, 35, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99)
For i = UBound(MyArray) To LBound(MyArray) Step -1
Rows(MyArray(i)).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

The reason I split it up over three different macro's is because when I try to fill myArray with the complete set of numbers, it says the statement is incorrect. I assume this has to do with the maximum amount of numbers I can add in the Array? Is this correct and does anyone know a workaround?

P.S.: I know this might not be the most efficient way to do it but I figured if I start from the bottom, I will delete the correct rows whereas if I start from the beginning, I would delete rows in a faulty way as 3 becomes 2 after you delete 2.

Comment: instead of delete, try to `.clearContents`, it will delete what is inside cells or `.clear` to clear formating also. And try to use something like this `Rows("1:50").entirerow.clear` where you can delete set of rows, instead of delete it one by one

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a maximum number of input arguments for the `Array` function but even if there was you haven't reached it yet. Your problem might be the maximum line length (up to 1024). Try to split up the numbers using `_`:

```
myArray  = Array(2, 6, 24, 30, 31, 34, 35, _
    ....., _
    911, 914, 915, 916, 923, 928)
```

edit: I could fit 2037 numbers inside an `Array(...)` command before getting a compile error (Too many local, nonstatic varaibles)

Answer (score 0):

I would not accomplish your task as you have (very inefficient).  However, to answer your question, I have read there is a limit of 1,024 characters in a physical line.  This can be overcome by using the line continuation character.

**EDIT**:

Here is a method using your row numbers, but combining them into a single range object:

```
Option Explicit
Sub dural()
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim I As Long

myArray = Array(2, 6, 24, 30, 31, 34, 35, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106, 107, 109, 112, 113, 114, 116, 120, 127, 139, 141, 148, 151, 165, 172, 185, 187, 189, 191, 196, 198, 201, 237, 240, 242, 243, 244, 246, 249, 253, 256, 271, 276, 282, 322, 323, 325, 330, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447 _
455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 578, 593, 628, 638, 643, 679, 683, 754, 755, 759, 817, 826, 830, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 881, 885, 891, 892, 899, 900, 905, 911, 914, 915, 916, 923, 928)

Set myRange = Rows(myArray(0))
For I = 1 To UBound(myArray)
    Set myRange = Union(myRange, Rows(myArray(I)))
Next I

myRange.Clear

End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of a message box containing the range addresses in `MyRange`:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for taking out time to to reply! Would you mind giving me a clue what function or method I could use to check to improve efficiency please?

Comment: I would create a range object, and then use Clear or Clearcontents in a single step

Comment: This makes perfect sense and seems like a very good way to accomplish what I was trying to do. Thanks alot and I will keep these in mind in the future. I didn't know this was actually possible in excel (relatively new to macros).

Comment: @Pieter I posted some additional code to show you how it might be done.  If you could mark my response as the answer, I would appreciate it.